# read() differences between python 2 and python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, newline, python-2.x, line-endings

With the following MWE:

```
with open('a','w') as f:
    f.write('\r')
with open('a','r') as f:
    print(ord(f.read()))
```

I get the following output:

```
$ python2 test.py 
13
$ python3 test.py 
10
```

Can you explain why? `13` is the expected decimal number of `\r` in ascii and UTF-8 as far as I can tell.

Comment: `ord('\n')` will give you 10. ShadowRanger has explained the reasons.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Python 3's `open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) defaults to universal newlines mode (`newline=None`), while [Python 2's `open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) only enables universal newlines mode if the mode string include `U`.

In universal newlines mode, a sequence `\r` (old Mac), `\n` (UNIX) or `\r\n` (DOS/Windows) are all recognized as newlines, and automatically converted to `\n` so line endings have a consistent representation to simplify string manipulation.

If you want universal newlines in Python 2, you can either use the mode string to enable it or [use `io.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open), which is a near exact equivalent of Python 3's built-in `open` (`io.open` on Python 3 is just another way to say `open`).

If you want to disable universal newlines handling on Python 3, pass `open` an argument of `newline=''` (for universal recognition for the purposes of breaking lines when reading/iterating, but no translation of line endings) or `newline='\n'` (for example) to mean only `\n` is recognized as a line ending at all, and again, no translation of line endings is performed. Passing `newline=''` is required to properly handle certain file formats; the `csv` module performs its own line ending handling, and `newline=''` ensures no information is lost before it reaches the `csv` reader.

Comment: @noleti: We will never, ever be over it. I expect to go to my grave with most languages created before 2010 or based on pre-2010 languages still treating `\r` specially, and quite a few new languages continuing to do so out of habit. It's not like `\r` is commonly used on its own anyway; if people are seeing it in text inputs, it's either hacky console control redirected to a file, or it was intended to act as a newline; either way, treating it as a newline is going to be more reasonable than ignoring it in most cases.